# Best resources for a Java developer working on .NET solutions

Tags: java, .net

My company has acquired several companies lately. We are a Java shop but have both VB .NET and C# .NET code bases now. I am about to start supporting these systems and am having trouble find good resources for finding the parallels/differences in .NET and Java. I have seen a few books but cannot decide which to buy, they all seem basically the same. It would be nice if anyone knows of resources that are online instead of having the information buried in a 700 page black and white book.

Specifically, I would like to find some resources that compare the macro and micro level differences. Including things like "what is the .NET equivalent of HashMap, ArrayList and Queue", and "How do I interact with a database" or "What are the differences between ASPs and JSPs".

I am really looking for some opinions about which resources are the best from people who have been in a similar situation (Java developer to .NET).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN.  Seriously, MSDN is quite possibly the best-technical level documentation there is for the nuts and bolts of the C# libraries.  Alternately, if you want a more exhaustive treatment, something like "CLR via C#" by Jeffrey Richter really gives you a good feel for what the CLR is capable of.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I had not seen that book in my previous searches. Thanks for the good find.

Answer (score 4):

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx37x362.aspx), most importantly the [Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx), and bookmark the [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx).

I'm from a Java background and recently started using C# and found the MSDN very helpful. The auto-complete search field often found me the reference page I was looking for.

Force yourself to learn [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx). It's beautiful once it clicks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The MSDN looks like a pretty exhaustive collection. I have used it in the past for VB6 topics and found it somewhat useful but never quite what I was looking for, maybe the .NET support is better.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting LINQ. I have never heard of this feature, and based on the one of the apps I am about to support, this is most likely being used extensively.

Comment: I read through the programming guide almost entirely before starting to code and I found it answered a lot of the little silly questions about syntax, which I find the most annoying while learning a new language.